# A quote by Niccolò Machiavelli

Tags: translation

Can anyone find the original of this quote by Machiavelli? «Men generally judge more by the eye than the hand,for everyone can se few can feel. Everyone sees what you appear to be, few really know what you are.»

Answer (score 4):

Da `Il Principe`, capitolo XVIII

```
Gli uomini in universale giudicano più agli occhi che alle mani, perché tocca a vedere
a ciascuno, a sentire a pochi. Ognun vede quel che tu pari, pochi sentono quel che tu sei.
```